# Not able to get a short code for the following

Tags: java, variables, operators

How to make a shorter version of the code 4th line ?

```
int first = 8;
int second = 19;
first = first + second ;
second = first - second ;
first = first - second ;
```

I was able to figure the following short code of the statements on the 3rd and 5th line as following :

```
first += second ;
first -= second ;
```

But wasn't able to get the same for the 4th line . I don't even know if it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
first -= second ;
```

mean `first = first - second;`

in line 4 you if you write

```
second -= first ; // second = second - first;
second -= second; // second = second - second;
```

So you cannot archive what you want `second = first - second;`

> I don't even know if it is possible to do so

Then it impossible to do.

For the shortest version

```
int first = 8, second = 19;
first = (first += second) - (second = first - second);
```

Comment: Can u try solving this ?
https://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem/view/bjp4/chapter2/s15-firstSecond2

Comment: I don't know what's wrong your answer or the website, coz it still shows FAIL

Answer (score 0):

if you give the shorthand expression as x +=y, it is converted to x = x + y; and it is executed. but for your case, order is changed and cannot achieved by shorthand operation